# On Windows 11 22H2 (22621), which registry keys controls whether a user folder is shown at system tree view?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, windows-11

After upgrading to Windows 11 22H2 (22621), most user folders (Music, Pictures, Downloads, Videos, etc.) are removed from default explorer view to "make explorer look cleaner". There is an option to "show all folders" but then the tree view on the left side of explorer will be very crowded with all Control Panels shown.

I tried to unhide user folders in Explorer by removing "HideIfEnabled" property in all `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\MyComputer\NameSpace\` subkeys. Then those hidden folders show up in Explorer, but they still won't show in tree view even though the property "System.IsPinnedToNameSpace" is set to 1 on all folders' "HKCR\CLSID" entries.

Is there a registry key somewhere else that controls the appearance of icons in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

user167420

I had the same question, and solved it as follows:

**1 File Explorer:**

- I switched off **Show All folders**
- I removed all pinned items
- In the File Explorer options, under General > Open File Explorer to, I chose **This PC**
  This left me with a two section navigation pane (OneDrives - divider - This PC) opening to This PC, but without direct links to 'Desktop', 'Documents' and 'Downloads'. Ultimately, I used **WinaeroTweaker** to achieve this.

**2 WinaeroTweaker**

**File Explorer** category > **Customize This PC Folders** subcategory

There you have two options to add folders: **Add custom folder** seemed to be the best solution.

I used this and used a display name containing middots for easy retrieval in the registry.

[image: less crowded File Explorer Navigation pane]